# Extract user email address in Laravel with Artisan::call

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know how can I put $user->email in the following code snippet, where the email address is. Everything works well when hard coded in but not when I put $user->email where the email address is - I get error then. Please help. thanks.

```
        public function runCommand(Request $request){
          $user = User::all();
          $signature = $request->input('signature');
          $command =  Artisan::call($signature, ['user' => 'myemail@email.co.za']);
          return response($command);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = User::all();
```

returns a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-collections)

The following illustrates how you iterate over all user emails:

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->email;
}
```

( In case you want to send an email to the currently authenticated user (?) from within a Controller, not a Command [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user). )

Comment: You can get the authenticated user also with auth()->user(), 
to recap: $user = auth()->user();